# magento 2 customer groups get group_renderer in system configuration

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer-group

I need to display all customer groups in dropdown in magento2 admin configuration but customer group_renderer is not working. can anyone please help me.

```
public function _prepareToRender()
    {  
        /** @var CustomAdminConfigHelperData $helper */
        $helper = $this->helperData;


        $this->addColumn('referral_url', ['label' => __('Referral URL / Domain'),'style' => 'width:200px']);
        $this->addColumn('customer_group', ['label' => __('Customer Group'),'style' => 'width:200px','renderer' => $this->_getGroupRenderer()]);

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }
    protected function  _getGroupRenderer() 
    {
        if (!$this->_itemRenderer) { 
            $this->_itemRenderer = $this->viewLayoutFactory->create()->createBlock(
                'Customergroupauto/GroupConfig/Groups', '',
                ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]
            );
        }
        return $this->_itemRenderer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 /**
 * Customer Group
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection
 */
protected $_customerGroup;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup,        
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_customerGroup = $customerGroup;        
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
/**
 * Get customer groups
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getCustomerGroups() {
    $customerGroups = $this->_customerGroup->toOptionArray();
    array_unshift($customerGroups, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>'Any'));
    return $customerGroups;
}
```

Comment: thanks for update but i need to customer group down in Column.

Comment: like dropdown???

Comment: yes, i like all group names come under dropown

Comment: then you just need to add `<field id="link" translate="label" type="select"
                    sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">` **type="select"** in the `configuration (system.xml)`

Comment: I need to pass the data like this 'renderer' => $this->_getGroupRenderer()